# Displays Highcharts with portion of given data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So i'm using "Stacked Column", given this example

```
$("#chart_container").highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'red',
    data: [1,1,22,4,2,5]
  }]
})
```

So the scenario is to display only **two**, **three**, **four** on the chart , then whenever user click on **left**/**right** arrows , the data will be shifted left or right.
For example , when user click the left arrow, the chart will display **one**, **two**, **three**

Is there anyway we can achieve this with Highcharts itself? ( without any custom javascript added )

Comment: What does "custom javascript" mean? If you want it only using JSON attribute-value pairs then no. It will require some amount of code.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there's nothing built in to support this, but a rather small amount of Javascript combined with some of Highcharts functions is enough.

For example, utilizing jQuery with Highcharts `setExtremes`, it would look like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(chart.xAxis[0].min-1, chart.xAxis[0].max-1);
        break;

        case 39: // right
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(chart.xAxis[0].min+1, chart.xAxis[0].max+1);
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3pqptsj8/2/) of it in action. To cap it at the start and end you could just add some logic depending on your categories and span width as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kar7q8oc/).